# Split string with a regular expression but omit empty results

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string by one or more occurrences of space or comma.
My first take was:

```
re.split(r'[,\s]+', s)
```

But when I give it a string like this, it returns empty strings at the start and end.

```
>>> re.split(r'[,\s]+', '  foo,  bar,  baz,')
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '']
```

How can I modify the pattern such that the empty results at the beginning and end go away?

I tried negative lookahead and lookbehind, but I couldn't get the results I want. Also, I prefer not to add extra code to filter out the empty strings if this can be done by the regular expression alone.

Comment: `re.findall(r'[^,\s]+', '  foo,  bar,  baz,')`

Comment: Probably you could use filter() `import re
list(filter(None, re.split(r'[,\s]+', '  foo,  bar,  baz,')))`